# pandas boxplot, groupby different ylim in each subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe and I would like to plot it as:

```
>>> X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 3)))
>>> X['NCP'] = np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)
>>> X[X['NCP'] == 0] += 100
>>> X.groupby('NCP').boxplot()
```

The result is what I want but all the subplots have the same ylim. This makes impossible to visualize the result properly. How can I set different ylim for each subplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you asked for was to set the y axis separately for each axes.  I believe that should be `ax.set_ylim([a, b])`.  But every time I ran it for each axes it updated for all.

Because I couldn't figure out how to answer your question directly, I'm providing a work around.

```
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 3)))
X['NCP'] = np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)
X[X['NCP'] == 0] += 100

groups = X.groupby('NCP')

print groups.groups.keys()

# This gets a number of subplots equal to the number of groups in a single 
# column.  you can adjust this yourself if you need.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(groups.groups), 1, figsize=[10, 12])

# Loop through each group and plot boxplot to appropriate axis
for i, k in enumerate(groups.groups.keys()):
    group = groups.get_group(k)
    group.boxplot(ax=axes[i], return_type='axes')
```

[`subplots` DOCUMENTATION](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots)

Comment: It works.  I think this is a bug as I am quiet sure that I was able to do it with my not working code.