# How to enable not sharing y axis of boxplot by categories in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to `plot` `boxplots` by category of an `excel` data.
Here is my sample `excel`: [image]

First, I want to define categories according to lemons column.For *example*, I want to define **ranges** for **lemon** and categorize **apples** and **oranges** according to these ranges. After that, I want to plot `boxplot` of this `dataframe` by `categories`. I am doing this with the following code:

```
def categories(dl):
    if dl > 5: return 'Best'
    elif 3 > dl : return 'Worst'
df["Categories"] = df['lemons'].map(categories)
df.boxplot(by='Categories')
```

But, when I do it like that, graphs share `y axis`. But They should not. How can I change this?

Comment: I think you need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148830/different-ylim-for-shared-axes-in-pandas-boxplot)

Comment: I saw it and tried to adapt but I could not. @jezreal

Comment: Do you need 3 columns of Categories?

Comment: Or what was problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 3 columns of categories? @jezrael