# Pandas boxplot, different y axes in subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

First, to say. I'm aware of similar questions namely [pandas-boxplot-groupby-different-ylim-in-each-subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352616/pandas-boxplot-groupby-different-ylim-in-each-subplot) and [different-ylim-for-shared-axes-in-pandas-boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148830/different-ylim-for-shared-axes-in-pandas-boxplot/40148917) but I am still not able to get the desired result with my dataset. I've got a dataset of wastewater samples where columns are different pollutants and rows with "codes" for three different groups:

Dataset looks like this (but bigger)

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Group': pd.Series(['IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT']),
                  'COD' : pd.Series([800, 900, 100, 400, 450, 500]),
                  'BOD' : pd.Series([40, 50, 60, 20, 25, 30])}
```

and my code for boxplot (in jupyter with matplotlib inline)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,  5))
data.boxplot(['COD','BOD'], 'Group', ax)
```

and the output is like this

[image: boxplot output]

It's obvious that the y-axis can't be the same for all the data, but I was not able to recreate the output in such way to change the axis for individual subplots even with help of the links above. I would really a appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you could do this create different axes for the subplots and plotting the dataframe columns separately:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
data.boxplot('COD','Group', ax=ax[0])
data.boxplot('BOD','Group', ax=ax[1])
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to create your axes using `sharey=False` *before* calling `DataFrame.boxplot()` to force the non-sharing of y-axes limits. **But you have to be careful to provide the correct number of axes**, otherwise pandas is forced to clear the figure and create it's own axes (which will then share their y-axes).

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(data.Group.unique()),figsize=(10,  5), sharey=False)
data.boxplot(['COD','BOD'], 'Group', axs)
```

[image]